# $g(x)=c$ solves the ODE $y'=f(y)$ iff $c$ is a critical point of the ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider the autonomous ODE $y'=f(y)$ where $f$ is continuously
> differentiable. $g(x)=c$ (where $c$ is a constant) solves this ODE if
> and only if $c$ is a critical point of the ODE. Remember to prove in
> both directions.

My attempt at the solution:

First, I need to show that if $g(x)=c$ is a solution of the ODE then $c$ is a critical point of the ODE.

So if $g(x)=c$ is a solution of $y'=f(y)$ then we have

$y'=f(y)=f(c)$ by definition for all $x$.

Since $f(c)$ is a constant, then $y=c$ is also a solution of the ODE.

If we do $\frac{d}{dy} f(y) = f'(y)$ at the point $y=c$, then we have $f'(c)=0$ because the derivative of a constant function is always zero. Thus $c$ is a critical point of the ODE.

Second, I need to show the converse is true. Namely, if $c$ is a critical point of the ODE, then $g(x)=c$ is a solution of the ODE.

So if $c$ is a critical point, that means $f(c)=0$. To show that $g(x)=c$ is a solution of the ODE, we need to show that $y'=f(y)=f(c)$ for all $x$.

Since $f(c)=0$ then $f(y)$ is constant at $y=c$ so when $y=c$, $y'=f(y)=f(c)$ for all $x$.

Is this a correct proof?

Comment: So if $c$  is a critical point, that means $f′(c)=0.$ No it's $f(c)=0$

Comment: @user577215664 ah yes, I made the appropriate changes, is it correct now?

Comment: No, it's not at all correct. Maybe it would help if you used the notation $y(x)$ instead of $g(x)$? You seem not to have realized that if you substitute the constant function $g(x)=c$ for $y$, then you'll need to substitute $0$ for $y'$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In proving the first direction ($\implies$), the crucial starting point is not that $y'=f(y)=f(c)$ for all $x$, but that $y'=g'(x)$ and $f(y)=f(c)$ imply that $g'(x)=f(c)$ for all $x$. Since $g(x)=c$ is a constant, we have that $g'(x)=0$ for all $x$ and therefore $f(c)=0$ and $c$ is a critical point.

For the second direction ($\impliedby$), $c$ being a critical point means that $y'=f(c)=0$ by definition. $y'=g'(x)=0$ for all $x$, so $g(x)=c$ is a solution to the ODE.